# Css not getting applied on button

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

```
css ->
.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

my template ->

```
<template v-slot:actions-slot="{ row }">
    <Button v-if="canManageDeliveryPlan" variant="tertiary" small @click="handleCreatePlanClick(row)">
     <span  v-bind:class="[row.shipmentStatus === 'CANCELLED' && row.deliveryOrderCount == 0 ? 'disabled' : '']">v-if="!row.wasModifiedByUser">Create plan</span>
      <span  v-bind:class="[row.shipmentStatus === 'CANCELLED' && row.deliveryOrderCount == 0 ? 'disables' : '']" v-if="row.wasModifiedByUser">Edit plan</span>
```

Comment: two possible problems could be: first, your ternary condition isn't getting fulfilled. or another could be typo of 'disables' as class name in second span

Comment: @James : good catch ,but entire row with chckbox doesnt get disabled,but button doesn

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply the class to the `button` element, not a `span` inside the button element.

```
<Button v-if="canManageDeliveryPlan" :class='myClass' variant="tertiary" small @click="handleCreatePlanClick(row)">
```

```
// computed ( or use a computed ref in vue3)
computed: {
 myClass() {
  const disabled = 
   row.shipmentStatus === 'CANCELLED' && row.deliveryOrderCount == 0
  return {disabled}
 }
}
```